# How do I get the first parameter from http request

Tags: php, html, routes

I am using Laravel 8. The user clicks on a link that includes an id# (`http://wxyz.abc/2`) My app receives a $request from the browser and  sends it to the store function via `Route::post('/comments', [CommentController::class, 'store']);`
My question is How do I get the id# into a php variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a route parameter:

```php
Route::post('/comments/{id}', [CommentController::class, 'store']);
```

In your controller:

```php
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
  echo $id;
}
```

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/requests

Comment: Lars Flieger, I have added the $id. Now I get "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\commentController::store(), 1 passed in "